# JavaScript RegEx Replace all but one word contains substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all word in except one word. the first word that contains "Thewo"

How can i do this with a RegEx?

Input String "We need to remove something from and keep a word Theword and save only first word Thewood Theworld"

Expted exsult: Theword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
input.match(/\w*Thewo\w*/)
```

Since you are asking for the first word that **contains** "Thewo", I assume that "Thewo" can appear in the middle of a word. For example, it will match `notTheworker` in `"and notTheworker here"`.